# How to create time intervals between specific publications in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, rails-activejob

I try to build a recipes web app. It is a kind of “game”. Each user have the possibility to like a recipe. At first, this one appears empty. And then, the user is supposed to receive each hour (or half hour) at intervals, each step of the recipe.

For the moment, I have these models :

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
has_many :steps
has_many :favorites
has_many :favorited_by_users, :through => :favorites, :source => 'user'

class Step < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :recipe
end

class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :recipe
belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :recipes
has_many :favorites
has_many :favorite_recipes, :through => :favorites, :source => 'recipe’

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

In my Step Controller i have :

```
def index
@recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id]) 
@steps = @recipe.steps
end
```

And I would like to display in my index step view :

Each step of the recipe the user liked, but one by one with a delay (1mn or 10 mn between each publication, whatever… something configurable). And is it possible to hide the name of the step, and display it after clicking on it ?

```
#views/steps/index.html.erb

<h2><%=Recipe.name%></h2>
<% @steps.each do |step| %>

<p>    <%=step.name%></p>
#30mn later… the second step
<p>    <%=step.name%></p>
#30mn later… the third one…
<p>    <%=step.name%></p>
```

Etc…

How is it possible ? Should I use cron or Active Job ? But How can I do ?

In advance thanks a lot ! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cron` or `Active Job` is definitely NOT what you are looking for. Such tools are used for server processing, while you in your task need client processing. What you really need to do is just to send an **ajax** request using javascript each 10mn to the server with number of step, that you need.

Keep in mind, that you need to make your step requests secure and store the time on server side when user got his last step. If you receive request earlier, then you planned, that you should decline it (you need such protection, because technical users can research your logic and try to send requests manually to retrieve further instructions.

How could your JS code look like:

```
setInterval(10000, function loadStep() {
  ajax.get([url], function(stepData) {
    // Some logic to display your step on the page
  })
})
```

Don't forget to setup proper route, that will accept such requests on server side

Comment: @Mehdi007 You are welcome! It would be great if you mark my code as a valid response with tick if it would help you (for future searches)

Comment: Hi, just one question, after render all steps and then execute javascript to display it, how can I avoid that after page reloads, it begin from step 1 each time ?

Comment: @Mehdi007 Then you should think about some logic, that will store your current step on the backend and will display your current step on reload

Answer (score 0):

You could render all steps in DOM and then execute javascript to display your steps, but that would mean that every time your page reloads, you would begin from step 1 again.

If you want to persist the advancements, you need to store the advancements in a table somewhere which reference the recipe and the user.

After that it's a matter a choosing your rule to check the advancements, regular Ajax query to register an newly displayed steps etc etc.

Comment: If you're rendering all steps into the DOM, it would be _very_ easy for a user to access these ahead of time, no?

Comment: Yes it would, but since I have no idea if it really is important or not in this case, I suggested it anyway.